# Selecting points that have minimum value than others within subset in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I have large-sized spatial joined data and in my attribute table, 'class1' is the value and 'ITID' is the subset. I want to select only one minimum value per subset from 'class1' which is within subset 'ITID'.

What should I do?

Attribute sample is in below.
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the Summary Statistics tool?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the "Select by Attributes" feature in the attribute table? (Open attribute table -> Table Options -> Select by Attributes) You should be able to write a query to select the values that you need. I am relatively new to GIS, so if you are experienced you may have already tried that.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't really get the whole thing. If you can provide some more information, screenshots or something like that...

Anyhow, I would advise you that if you are running large files use permanent unions of tables (JOIN FIELD TOOL) as it would importantly decrease your computational time. You can undo it afterwards with the tool DELETE FIELD.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the attribute table in my question.

Comment: So you want to select of every *ITID* the point with the lowest *class1* value? But what about if you have 3 value *1* like happens in *ITID* =9995?

Comment: If possible, among them (*ITID*=9995) i want to select only one minimum value prioritize by 'species', otherwise select only one minimum value ramdomly.

Comment: I am afraid you should write some code of that if you want a multiple selection. Check, for instance: https://community.esri.com/thread/83329

Comment: i think it can be done by an ‘expression’

Comment: Is it possible in Qgis without code?